# telnet fails to connect: Connection closed by foreign host

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, telnet

I try to connect to localhost with telnet:

```
% telnet localhost 6311
```

This connection succeed, but when I connect by external IP of my computer, connection fails:

```
% telnet x.x.x.x 6311
Trying x.x.x.x...
Connected to x.x.x.x
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Firstly, the site address. Try on SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: I checked :

% sudo telnet x.x.x.x 6311

same problem...

Comment: It's not a web server there, it is RServe.. 
Then I don't have any site address...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the service ( that was running on 6311)
The servise just was not configured to work with remote access.

It means, telnet was OK :)

Answer (score 1):

Check what IP server is listening to. I am suspecting that your server is listening to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. Make it listen to `0.0.0.0` (probably via some conf file).

You can verify it by running

```
netstat -tapnl | grep 6311
```

Check if it shows `127.0.0.1:6311` or `0.0.0.0:6311`

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, you can mark this as accepted answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

first you need to see the ubuntu system log with this command

**sudo gedit /var/log/syslog**

and if you will see this error "execv( /usr/sbin/tcpd ) failed: No such file or directory" then run this command

**sudo apt-get install tcpd**

it will solve your problem (if not then you need to search your system error on google)